# meteorjs minimongoid + autoform

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get minimongoid to work with meteorjs but I get an error statement:

```
Error: AutoForm: collection attribute for form with id "insertBuildingForm" is not a Meteor.Collection instance
```

Does that mean that a minimongoid collection is not considered as a Meteor collection and that I cannot have it to play with autoform? Or am I doing something wrong?

If minimongoid and autoform are not compatible, what is the best way to manage validation with minimongoid? I mean automatically...  ;-)

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, using this:

EDIT: With the release of collection2 2.0, the API has changed and you MUST use attachSchema ie

```
class @Book extends Minimongoid

    @_collection:  new Meteor.Collection('books')

Book._collection.attachSchema new SimpleSchema({
    name:
      type: String
      label: "Name"
      max: 200
    author:
      type: String
      label: "Author"
    publishedDate:
      type: Date
      label: "Publication Date"
    price: 
      type: Number
      label: "Price" 
      min: 0
})
```

Then in the html template

```
{{> quickForm collection="Book._collection" id="insertBookForm" type="insert"}}
```

Notice the collection should be `Book._collection`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this means the minimongoid collection is not compatible, unless it is an extension of Meteor.Collection.

The line that does this is here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/e77832d40f8eec2ddb92d97f481bf86fb712d9ca/utility.js#L261-L263

It's hard to say how to do it with minimongoid, since it is not a core package. It does support validation itself though.

```
validate: ->
  unless @name and @name.length > 3
    @error('name', 'Recipe name is required and should be longer than 3 letters.')
```

The way it supports validation is via the Collection.insert rules (I think?). So at the point where you try and insert the document you will get this error, similar to how the Access Denied error works when you remove the `insecure` package.

There is also client side validation, you would have to check the `errors` attribute via e.g via `Recipe.errors.length`